# if comparison fails when script is sourced

Tags: bash, unix, zsh

Below is the mwe which reads an input and
compares with character 'a'. 
It works fine when invoked as it is.

```
read  -n 1  inp
if [ $inp = 'a' ]
then
    echo "Hello"
fi
```

However, when sourced it gives
error:

```
parse error: condition expected: =
```

Comment: Enclose your variables in double quotes inside `[ ... ]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the script you source it from runs with `zsh`, not `bash`.

Sourced scripts are always run with the shell that does the sourcing, regardless of shebang. Your script is written for `bash` and is incompatible with `zsh`, so it fails.

The equivalent `zsh` code is:

```
read  -k 1  inp
if [ "$inp" = 'a' ]
then
    echo "Hello"
fi
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am using zsh :). Thank you.